# Pair of Mirrors Facing Each Other

Tags: optics, reflection

If you have two mirrors facing each other and you introduce a light source into the reflections and you take the light source away, would it immediately go away for all reflections in the "tunnel" of reflections?

Comment: It wouldn't go away right away but it would go away faster than any human could observe.  Mirrors don't reflect 100% of light anyway, so a single photon might survive a handful of reflections back and forth before being absorbed and turned into heat.   Now if you set up an experiment in empty space with mirrors several thousands of miles apart you might be able to catch a delayed reflection after turning off the light source.

Comment: I was thinking of doing this with something like http://www.extremetech.com/computing/162322-mit-creates-the-first-perfect-mirror in theory.

Comment: @userLTK *"single photon might survive a handful of reflections back and forth before being absorbed"* -- What about high-Q cavities?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch You got me there.   I don't know the answer to that one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mirror reflection](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86493/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do light disappears the moment we switch off the source (inside the wooden box)?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90892/)